# Google cloud - enable billing on project programactally

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a web app deployed in a GCE instance since last year, but yesterday my access to this instance was suspended since my free credits ended so i need to enable billing on my project.

I forgot my email address to enter in my google cloud account, so i can't log in and enable billing on my project. I have valid credentials that i used to interact with Google Compute Engine, it's possible to enable billings on my project using some google cloud api?

I've searched here: https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/?apix=true#rest-resource-v1billingaccounts but not found anything.

How can i enable billing on my project using the api?

Comment: If you have lost your email address/credentials to the Google Cloud Console, then you will need to contact Google Cloud Billing Support. https://cloud.google.com/support/billing

Comment: I tried @JohnHanley, but they told me that is not possible to tell me the email i used in the account =/

Comment: But they can send an email to that address - Ask. How many do you have? Can you access all of your email accounts? There is nothing we can do to help you on Stack Overflow.